# vb.net - Keep label centered even when it's text is changed?

Tags: vb.net, alignment, label

So I've got this label, which is initially in the center of... let's call it a field. Not in the center of any control, but a center of a small rectangular field near the bottom of my form. (This field is **not** a control, but part of the form's background image)

Now, when the label changes it's text length, the label's width gets increased and grows towards the left side, however, I want it to retain in the center of this "field".

Basically I want to replicate the same effect as if you were to center align text in a richtextbox, but instead, with a label.

Is there anything I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for WinForms:**

Using the Forms Designer resize your label to be wide exactly as your underlying box `(AutoSize=False`) then set the [TextAlign](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.textalign(v=vs.110).aspx) property to [ContentAlignement.MiddleCenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.contentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You're a savoir! Thank you so much!